# Probability of picking exactly needed number of useful balls

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are 40 balls in a box. 4 are white and rest 36 are black.
If one randomly pick 20 balls from the box, what is the probability of getting 1 white ball? 2 white balls? 3 white balls? 4 white balls?

Also, I repeat this experiment n times to collect total 100 picks of white balls.
How do one calculate this **n** ?

Comment: Can you compute the chance of getting no white balls?  What is your background?  If there were just one white ball can you compute the chance of getting it?

Comment: Yes, I can compute the chance of getting no white balls. (36c20)/(40c20)

Comment: So for one white ball you need to pick one of four white balls and nineteen of thirty-six black ones.  Compute the number of ways to do that and compare with the number of ways to pull twenty of forty

Comment: Problem I'm seeing is, when I followed this approach, I get probability of getting 1 ball and 3 balls as same. I think my thoughts are totally flawed here. So, seeking some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chance of getting $1$ is $$\frac {{4 \choose 1}{36 \choose 19}}{40 \choose 20}=\frac {120}{481}$$
The chance of getting $3$ is equal to the chance of getting $1$.  If you draw and get $1$ the remaining balls are a draw that would give you $3$.